# Call another method of the same "class" with this context being different in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, reference, this

I am working on a wrapper of `WebSocket` and I am having a problem about the `this` context. Please note, I already understand *why* the problem happens by reading StackOverflow articles, but now *how* to solve it.

Here is my current class

```
MusicArena.JsonWebSocket = function (url, onOpen, onMessage, onError) {
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket(url);
    this.webSocket.onmessage = this.onRawMessage.bind(this); // This is fine

    // This key is used by the decode method, and in the future might get value from a parameter.
    this.encryptionKey = ENCRYPTION_KEY;

    // Other iniitalization code.
};


MusicArena.JsonWebSocket.constructor = MusicArena.JsonWebSocket;

MusicArena.JsonWebSocket.prototype.decode = function (encoded) {
    // Process the encrypted message
};

MusicArena.JsonWebSocket.prototype.onRawMessage = function (event) {
    var data = event.data;
    var decoded = this.decode(data);

    var obj = JSON.parse(decoded);
    if (DEBUG) {
        console.log(obj);
    }

    if (obj) {
        this.onMessage(obj.ID, obj.Action, obj);
    };
};

// Other codes
```

The problem is that `onRawMessage` can be being called outside of the class by my program and other developers, and so the `this` in `this.decode()` does not point to my class anymore. Is there a way to call `decode` within the `onRawMessage` without making user have to bind the `JsonWebSocket` instance?

Comment: Can you give an example of usage?

Comment: Why don't you invoke the function directly:  `MusicArena.JsonWebSocket.prototype.decode(data);`?

Comment: @KingMob I just simply initialize and call the method from outside (we have multiple HTML5 `WebSocket` instances at the same time), nothing special, just like the `this.webSocket.onmessage  = this.onRawMessage.bind(this);` without the `bind`, because it is being developed by other developers.

Comment: @Vidul Wow, seriously, it can be called like that? I didn't know that. Any disadvantage this way, or problem, or variable problem, for example if I use a variable assigned inside the constructor with `this.a = something;`?

Comment: @DatVM I don't understand the question about variable problem `this.a = simething` (this is just a property definition). No disadvantages or problems, however, if you don't need `decode` as method, you should probably remove it from the prototype chain and replace it with a function: `var decode = function(encoded) { ... }`.

Comment: @Vidul I added to the question my code, in the constructor, I define the `encryptionKey` property. I doubt the prototype function can understand they property, because it sticks to the instance, right?

Comment: @DatVM Not sure that I understood the question. Felix Kling's explanation should help you fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to ensure that `this` is always correct inside `onRawMessage` (i.e. points to the class instance) is to bind it inside the constructor:

```
this.onRawMessage = this.onRawMessage.bind(this);
```

> The problem is that `onRawMessage` can be being called outside of the class by my program and other developers, and so the this in `this.decode()` does not point to my class anymore.

IMO it's not necessarily your responsibility to ensure other developer's code works correctly. Of course it is nice to make it more convenient for them, but they should also expect that the method does not work without the correct instance, because that is the case for most methods.

Also, while they can certainly call the method, it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense since it expects a very specific event object. If they call it like `socket.onRawMessage(...)` then `this` will correctly point to `socket` anyway.

Comment: This is briliant! Thank you very much for your answer, as well as your advice. I will be discussing with them about this and decide whether they have to bind the instance, or I do this myself. In my environment where there are multiple `WebSocket` events with the same processing, it does make sense though :)